# Is there a way to check multiple pods in one kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to check multiple pods in one command, perhaps something like

```
kubectl logs pods/pod1 pods/pod2 [container-name]
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `kubectl logs` can't print logs from multiple pods specified by names.

Although, you can use the `-l, --selector=''` flag as a label query to filter on. e.g.:

```
# Return snapshot logs from all containers in pods defined by label app=nginx
kubectl logs -lapp=nginx --all-containers=true
```

If you need to print logs from multiple different pods, there are some projects that can help:

- [Kubetail](https://github.com/johanhaleby/kubetail): Bash script that enables you to aggregate (tail/follow) logs from multiple pods into one stream. This is the same as running `kubectl logs -f` but for multiple pods.
- [Kubelogs](https://github.com/eduardobaitello/kubelogs): It is a bash script that uses your current `kubectl context` to interactively select namespaces and multiple pods to download logs from. It basically runs `kubectl logs` in a loop for all containers, redirecting the logs to local files.